# Need Help regarding UIImage and UIView capturing in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiview

I am adding `UIImage` dynamically and moving it on `UIView` and I have 4 buttons in bottom as well. 
What I want is to save `UIView` as image but I dont want buttons to save while saving that `UIView` and I want `UIImageView` to be added behind Buttons.

screenshot code

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

Adding UIImageView

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"lam.jpg"]];


    CGRect cellRectangle;
    cellRectangle = CGRectMake(20 ,50,image.size.width/6 ,image.size.height/6 );

    //[[self view] addSubview:blockView];
    UIImageView *dragger = [[Draggable alloc] initWithFrame:cellRectangle];
    [dragger setImage:image];
    [dragger setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    [self.view addSubview:dragger];
```

I have saved `UIView` as image like this but I dont want buttons to be saved. I have also used another `UIView` but I want whole screen to drag images thats my restriction. I hope that everyone got what I want. 
[image: The screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite get it. But as I understand you want a screenshot of the view with the cars, but without the buttons. Easiest solution would be to put a fullscreen view on your mainView. On that fullscreenView you put your car images. The buttons are also directly on the mainView. Than in your screenshot method you just use the fullscreenView instead of `self.view`.

Comment: i have added an UIVIew dynamically (320x460) . but its showing in front of Buttons. how can i add UIVIew behind those buttons.

Comment: Put a view, say named `screenshotView` on `self.view` but below your buttons. If you add an image, add it on that view: `[screenshotView addSubview:image]`. Adittional info: If you want to put a view below another view on the same superview you may use `insertSubview:belowView:`/`insertSubview:aboveView:` for that.

Comment: i m adding UIVIEW dynamically not from IB.

Comment: That does not change anything. I told you everything you need. Where is the problem? `self.screenshotView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.bounds]; [self.view addSubview: screenshotView]`. Afterwards add the buttons. And when you add images, or make the screenshot use that view. `[self.screenshotView addSubview:dragger];` etc.

Answer (score 2):

couldnt you just hide the buttons?

```
 for(UIButton *b in view.subviews) {
    if([b isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        b.hidden = YES;
    }
}

//capture view


for(UIButton *b in view.subviews) {
    if([b isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        b.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. it works fine. But is this the best way to do this? what about  jaydees have said about adding subview behine buttons and capture that? coz if app will delay then user can see buttons hidding and showing.

Comment: jaydee's idea would also work and will likely look better as there wont be any gfx glitches as you said...

Comment: In jaydees solution i am facing problem . My view is adding in front of Buttons . how can i add my UIView behind buttons?